# Run sed as a one-off ssh command

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ssh, sed

I would like to substitute a string with another in a file on a server of mine. I've tried doing this:

```
ssh $REMOTE_HOST sed 's|export ${KEY}=${VAL}|export ${KEY}=${NEW_VAL}|' "$ENV_FILE"
```

And a bunch of variants with different types of quoting, but I just can't make it work. The sed command works when I manually substitute the variables with the values and run it on the server.

The command above gives the following error:

```
bash: {env_file_redacted}: Permission denied
bash: line 0: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: line 0: export: `=': not a valid identifier
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unterminated `s' command
```

Like I said, the command works when I ran it on the server so it's not a permissions problem.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all variables (apart from $REMOTE_HOST) are available in the environment on your remote server you can try:

```
ssh $REMOTE_HOST 'echo sed "s|export ${KEY}=${VAL}|export ${KEY}=${NEW_VAL}|" "$ENV_FILE"'
```

And if everything looks fine, remove `echo`.

**Update**

With local variables:

```
ssh $REMOTE_HOST "echo sed \"s|export ${KEY}=${VAL}|export ${KEY}=${NEW_VAL}|\" \"$ENV_FILE\""
```

And if everything looks fine, remove `echo`.

Comment: The variables are on my local machine, not the remote one. Is that the problem? I feel so stupid right now, been working on this single line for hours...

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work, however even after I remove the echo nothing seems to get substituted. Do I need to give `sed` a flag for that?

Comment: If you want to edit in place in $ENV_FILE add option `-i` to sed. If nothing seems to get substituted then is something wrong with your search expression.

Comment: Syntax: `ssh server command`. If `command` contains blanks quote with `"`. If you use `"` your bash can substitute local variables. If your command contains `"` escape them with a backslash. If you don't want substitution use `'`.